# xcolor black isn't black enough

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, color-profile

I'm making a poster (using [baposter](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)) where I wish to include some microscopy images. To make the fluorescent signals stand out better, I changed the background of that cell to "pitchblack", which I have defined as

```
\definecolor{pitchblack}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
```

I've also tried this with

```
\definecolor{pitchblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
```

However, with my microscopy images in the foreground, I find out that "black" isn't really black:
[image]

The `baposter`class brings `xcolor` and `tikz` along for the ride, so I'm assuming my color issue is with those packages. So my question is, how I can make the "black" of the background frame black enough to match the background of these images?

Full code of the frame:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\headerbox{Preliminary Images}{name=prelim,column=2,row=0,boxColorOne=pitchblack}{
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\raisebox{-2ex}{
\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{\scriptsize\color{white} Representative volume renderings of HeLa cells imaged using TALEs
against the $\beta$-globin locus. Signals are approximately 0.3$\mu$m
in diameter.}} &
\imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{dataimages/5_02_volume_view.jpg}} & 
\imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{dataimages/5_04_volume_view.jpg}} \\ 
\imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{dataimages/5_05_volume_view.jpg}} & 
\imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{dataimages/5_07_volume_view.jpg}} & 
\imagetop{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{dataimages/5_10_volume_view.jpg}}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
```

As a final note, the problem appears to be independent of the pdf viewer (i.e. it looks this way in evince,acroread,and gimp).

Comment: In case the information is useful for you: The black in the microscopy image is R:0 G:0 B:0 D:255 100% and the pitchblack is R:35 G:31 B:32 D:255 100%.

Comment: That's interesting, but unsurprising. I guess my question really boils down to removing the minimal color that xcolor seems to insist on having.

Comment: Can you provide a full compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? I get `geometry` errors after wrapping your frame code between `\documentclass{baposter}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried to use the ``black`` color already defined in xcolor? I mean something like (in tikz) ``\fill[black] (0,0) circle 1;``... this should give you real black. If not, then there will definitely be some more examination and a MWE needed.

Comment: `baposter` loads `xcolor` by default with the option `cmyk`. All color models used now don't get it right. If you load the package option `rgb` and use `\definecolor{pitchblack}{gray}{0}` (or the equivalent RGB command, or the already defined `black`) it _is_ pitchblack.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Short answer: “K does not <sub><sup>[really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_plate)</sup></sub> stand for black”

```
\definecolor{pitchblack}{cmyk}{1 1 1 1}
```

## Long answer

This is a CMYK matter: `baposter` loads [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) by default with the package option `cmyk` anymore.
Even passing `rgb` to `xcolor` doesn't help here.

Nonetheless, one should issue a test print, colors are not always what they appear to be.

A monitor uses the additive color model *[RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)*, where your pixels consist of three sub-pixel. Additive means, that to have color one has to add light.
No output: black; full output: white.

A printer uses a subtractive color model like *[CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)*. Subtractive means removing light (when you add, for example, more *cyan* to your white paper, it will reflect less *red*).
No output: white (full reflection); full output: black.

#### Why is black not black?

[Good question!](https://www.google.com/#output=search&q=cmyk+black&oq=cmyk+black)
The output depends on so many factors like paper, printer, toner, …

Again, check your printed output. Even in different PDF viewer the colors that are not CMYK(0, 0, 0, 1) or CMYK(1, 1, 1, 1) are represented by different RGB values.

### Examples

In the following MWE I provide three new “pitch”blacks to compare:

```
                         Name            CMYK             RGB
                    ———————————————————————————————————————————————
                      pitchblack0    0   0   0   1    .35 .31 .32
                      pitchblack1   .6  .4  .4   1    .13 .12 .12
                      pitchblack2    1   1   1   1    .0  .0  .0
                      pitchblack3   .75 .68 .67 .9    .16 .14 .13
                      black          0   0   0   1    .35 .31 .32
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tabular]{standalone}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\definecolor{pitch0}{cmyk}{0 0 0 1}
\definecolor{pitch1}{cmyk}{.6 .4 .4 1}
\definecolor{pitch2}{cmyk}{1 1 1 1}
\definecolor{pitch3}{cmyk}{.75 .68 .67 .9}
\newcommand*\blackbox[1]{\color{#1}\rule[-1ex]{3cm}{2em}}
\begin{document}\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{lrrc}
    Color  &           CMYK &         RGB &      Output       \\
    pitch0 &        0 0 0 1 & .35 .31 .32 & \blackbox{pitch0} \\
    pitch1 &     .6 .4 .4 1 & .13 .12 .12 & \blackbox{pitch1} \\
    pitch2 &        1 1 1 1 &  .0  .0  .0 & \blackbox{pitch2} \\
    pitch3 & .75 .68 .67 .9 & .16 .14 .13 & \blackbox{pitch3} \\
    black  &        0 0 0 1 & .35 .31 .32 & \blackbox{black}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Fifty Shades of Grey]

Comment: Thank you! I was about to give up and fix it by hand in gimp.

Comment: @MarkKelly I've updated my answer with, hopefully, helpful details. I might add that common-sense black seems to be `pitch1` (.6 .4 .4 .1). In Adobe's Reader this is even rendered as RGB (0 0 0). If you can, issue a test print with my table and on of your space pictures. In the professional field, a print with `pitch2` (0 0 0 0) may rejected, because the “full load” of all colors is used to plot printer's marks (such as crop and registration marks).

Comment: I fear that this would not be black but a very thick layer of ink when printed. :)